# SseEmitter onError method behaves different in Tomcat and Glassfish/Payara

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events

I'm implementing server sent events in Spring MVC application with Payara 5. However, when there is error on emitter.send() (when client disconnected) emitter's onError method doesn't get called. When I try the same code on Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat everything works normal. Spring dependency versions are same on both applications.

```
@GetMapping("/listen-sse")
public SseEmitter sseEmitter() {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(0L);
    emitter.onError(e -> System.out.println("OnError"));

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    service.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                emitter.send("Hello");
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    service.shutdown();
    return emitter;
}
```

My dependencies in Spring MVC application:

```
<dependencies>
        <!--Spring resources-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring + aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but mine happens in Spring Boot's embedded tomcat. onCompletion, onTimeOut and onError never get called!

Comment: I recommend you to create a new question about this. I believe mine is about a bug in Payara, I've written to the Github issues page about this problem. I will update this if there is any progress